# How can I get only those picklist values in my visualforce page which corresponds to a particular selected value of its controlling picklist?

Tags: visualforce, picklist, dependent-picklist, schema

How can I get only those picklist values in my visualforce page which corresponds to a particular selected value of its controlling picklist?

I know about using Schema.getDescribe method to get the picklist values of a picklist field ,
But my requirement is to get only those picklist values which corresponds to the value selected by its controlling picklist field .

I dont wanna show them as picklists,I rather will display the corresponding labels in a form.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: As Abhijeet said, you need to use <apex:inputField>, Here is the example for the same. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm

Answer (score 2):

Using apex:inputfield in VF pages will handle field dependency  automatically.you dont need to handle it explicitly.

Comment: But I don't wanna show as a picklist,I wanna display all the dependent values in a form .

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena picklists can go in a form. Did you want the display to be radio select or checkboxes instead?

Comment: Yes exactly ,I wanna show them with checkbox select options.